# Hyperbolic isometries in the context of General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, mathematical-physics

In the context of [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry), it is possible to create a classification for [isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry).
I would like to know if these isometries have any particular meaning in the context of general relativity.
Is it possible to understand these isometries from the point of view of general relativity?

Answer (score -1):

There is a Bianchi classification of 3d Lie algebras upto isomorphism. Hence this also classifies all 3d Lie groups.

Now, in the ADM formalism of General Relativity, we consider the evolution of a 3d spatial slice. The symmetry group of this slice is a Lie group. When this symmetry group is 3d, we can use the Bianchi classification. This gives us a classification of Bianchi spacetimes.